# SQL query to find swipe-in swipe out in Office

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table "AccessDetails" with fields

1. employeeId
2. employeeName
3. Designation
4. Department
5. SwipeLocation
6. swipeTime
7. ReaderType

How can i get swipe details in a date range with this information. Here swipeTime gives date and time and ReaderType gives IN/OUT.

```
employeeID  employeeName    designation department  swipeLocation   swipetime   readerType
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D3  2014-07-10 19:55:00.000 IN
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-10 20:00:00.000 OUT
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-10 20:10:00.000 IN
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-10 20:20:00.000 IN
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-10 20:35:00.000 OUT
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-11 19:00:00.000 IN
1157    IRINA NALOBINA  Engineer    Operations  GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2  2014-07-11 20:35:00.000 OUT
```

Here i have employeeId 1157 have 2 days in/out details. If i select two dates 2014-07-11 and 2014-07-10, the result should be

```
1157 IRINA NALOBINA Engineer
Operations
GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D3(1st swipe in location)
2014-07-10 19:55:00.000(1st swipe in time)
GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2(Last swipe out location)
2014-07-10 20:35:00.000(last swipe out time)
```

AND

```
1157
IRINA NALOBINA
Engineer
Operations
GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2(1st swipe in location)
2014-07-11 19:00:00.000(1st swipe in time)
GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2(Last swipe out location)
2014-07-11 20:35:00.000(last swipe out time)
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. Looks like you need basic `select` query with `between` operator in `where` clause

Comment: `select * from AccessDetails where swipeTime between @dateFrom and @dateTo` where `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` are datetime variables for the date range.

Comment: What exactly should "swipe details" look like? Do you want each individual record returned between the date range (this is a pretty basic query)? Do you just want IN/OUT counts for each employee within the date range (a *slightly* more complex query)? Give us an example of data and the expected result from the query.

Comment: Kindly put some effort by starting with a select query

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(employeeID INT,employeeName VARCHAR(100), designation VARCHAR(100), department VARCHAR(100), swipeLocation VARCHAR(100), swipetime DATETIME, readerType VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D3',  '2014-07-10 19:55:00.000', 'IN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-10 20:00:00.000', 'OUT'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-10 20:10:00.000', 'IN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-10 20:20:00.000', 'IN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-10 20:35:00.000', 'OUT'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-11 19:00:00.000', 'IN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1157,    'IRINA NALOBINA',  'Engineer',    'Operations',  'GF_LIFT LOBY FL_D2',  '2014-07-11 20:35:00.000', 'OUT'
```

We need to find out the 1st and last swipe time for each date first, and find the locations for them thereafter. I have written the logic in detail inside the query.

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATE='2014-07-10'
DECLARE @TODATE DATE='2014-07-11'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Here we find out the 1st swipe in time and last swipe out time for an employee for each date
    SELECT 
    employeeID,employeeName,designation,department,
    swipeLocation,
    swipetime,
    MIN(CASE WHEN readerType='IN' THEN swipetime END) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(swipetime AS DATE)) MINDATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN readerType='OUT' THEN swipetime END) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(swipetime AS DATE)) MAXDATE
    ,readerType
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE CAST(SWIPETIME AS DATE) BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- We format th date column and location column with string
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MINDATE)RNO,
    CAST(employeeID AS VARCHAR(30))employeeID,employeeName,designation,department,  
    swipeLocation + (CASE WHEN readerType='IN' THEN '(1st swipe in location)' ELSE '(Last swipe out location)' END) swipeLocation,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),MINDATE, 121) + '(1st swipe in time)' MINDATE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),MAXDATE, 121) + '(Last swipe out time)' MAXDATE,
    readerType
    FROM CTE    
    WHERE swipetime=MINDATE OR swipetime=MAXDATE 
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Find out the 1st and last swipe location for 1st and last time on that date and keep in seperate columns
    SELECT C2.RNO,C2.employeeID,C2.employeeName,C2.designation,C2.department,C2.swipeLocation INLOC,C2.MINDATE,C2.MAXDATE,C2.readerType readerTypeIN,
    C3.swipeLocation OUTLOC,C3.readerType readerTypeOUT
    FROM CTE2 C2
    LEFT JOIN CTE2 C3 ON C2.RNO  = C3.RNO-1
)
-- We bring all the values to single column using CROSS APPLY
-- Since we get next record details in the same line in CTE3, we omit each row which are multiples of 2
SELECT CAST(COL AS NVARCHAR(300))COL
FROM CTE3
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(employeeID),(employeeName),(designation),(department),(INLOC),(MINDATE),(OUTLOC),(MAXDATE)) CS (COL)
WHERE RNO % 2 <> 0
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Did u get the output? @Sarat